# How to get WCF statistics from inside an application that uses it?

Tags: .net, wcf, performance, networking, monitoring

Is it possible to gather performance statistics programmatically from inside a WCF application? For example, the number of connections open or requests received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [WCF Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx). You can query performance counters using the respective  [.NET Framework Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx).

Also, you could enable WMI for your WCF Services and query this information from inside your application.

Probably depends on the kind of information you need to get.